# jQuery plugin and angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, selectize.js

in my application, written over angular, i have defined a directive for a particular type of input...

```
greengo.directive('selectize', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).selectize({ ... });
    }
};
```

});

the element is declared like this..

```
<select selectize context = "sensors" ng-model = "newSensor.id"></select>
```

it works fine.. but my model "newSensor.id" isn't updated when an option is selected...

where i'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To update the bound model value, your directive needs to call the $setViewValue method on the input directive's controller.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController

Perhaps something like this:

```
greengo.directive('selectize', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel', // require ng-model directive on element
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            $(element).selectize({
                // define onChange handler clled when value changes
                onChange: function(newValue) {
                    // set new model value, wrapped in scope.apply 
                    // since event is called outside AngularJS
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        modelCtrl.$setViewValue(newValue); 
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: ok, it works!! i have made something like this:

onChange: function(newValue) {
                // set new model value, wrapped in scope.apply 
                // since event is called outside AngularJS
                scope.$apply(attr.ngModel+" = "+newValue);
            }

but the real problem is: why, if that plug-in updates the dom and so the view, the model does not follows this update?

what part i'm missing in the understanding of angular?